# Find the singular matrix, with interchanged generalized eigenvectors of another singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a singular matrix $A$ with a non-semisimple double-zero eigenvalue. We can find its generalized eigenvectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ associated with the zero eigenvalue such that
\begin{equation}
Ae_1=0, \quad Ae_2=e_1.
\end{equation}

I am wondering how to find a matrix $B$ with a non-semisimple double-zero eigenvalue, such that
\begin{equation}
Be_2=0, \quad Be_1=e_2.
\end{equation}

Can we express $B$ explicitly, using $A$, $e_1$, and $e_2$?

---

After being reminded that $B$ is not unique, I want to revise the problem
to guarantee the uniqueness.

For matrix $A$, we find $e_1,\,e_2$ such that $Ae_1=0, \;Ae_2=e_1$.

For matrix $A^\top$, we find
$\varepsilon_1,\,\varepsilon_2$ such that
$A^\top \varepsilon_2=0, \;A^\top \varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_2$.

We also assume the normalization that
$\varepsilon_1^\top e_1=\varepsilon_2^\top e_2=1$, and
$\varepsilon_1^\top e_2=\varepsilon_2^\top e_1=0$.

Then, I'd like to find some matrix B, such that
\begin{equation}
BA+e_1\varepsilon_1^\top=I,\\
Be_2=0,
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the identity. If we multiply the first equation above
by $e_2$ on the right, we will have

\begin{equation}
BAe_2+e_1\varepsilon_1^\top e_2=Ie_2 \Rightarrow
Be_1=e_2.
\end{equation}

Question: can be express such $B$ with $A$, $e_i$, and $\varepsilon_i$
($i=1,2$)?

Comment: The matrix will not be unique since the number of unknowns is $n^2$ with only $2n$ equations.

Comment: I'm sorry for the miss. I have revised the problem so that we have at least $n^2$ equations.